# how programmatically select item by position in adapter (android)

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I want to select an item by position in adapter programmatically 
in my project i have an activity that get categories , now i want to select an item form this adapter automatic.

final result is : 
after Home activity have been lunched when user clicks on the button and lunch the second activity that getting my categories from web service in the adapter and then select an item by position at adapter and run third activity that shown the content of the item.

Here is my codes

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class FragmentCategory extends Fragment {

    private View root_view, parent_view;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipe_refresh;
    private AdapterCategory mAdapter;

    private Call<CallbackCategories> callbackCall = null;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        root_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, null);
        parent_view = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.main_content);

        swipe_refresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout) root_view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout_category);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) root_view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewCategory);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        //set data and list adapter
        mAdapter = new AdapterCategory(getActivity(), new ArrayList<Category>());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // on item list clicked
        mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterCategory.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View v, Category obj, int position) {
                ActivityCategoryDetails.navigate((ActivityMain) getActivity(), v.findViewById(R.id.lyt_parent), obj);
            }
        });




        // on swipe list
        swipe_refresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                mAdapter.resetListData();
                requestAction();
            }
        });

        requestAction();

        return root_view;
    }

    private void displayApiResult(final List<Category> categories) {
        mAdapter.setListData(categories);

        swipeProgress(false);
        if (categories.size() == 0) {
            showNoItemView(true);
        }
    }

    private void requestCategoriesApi() {
        API api = RestAdapter.createAPI();
        callbackCall = api.getAllCategories();
        callbackCall.enqueue(new Callback<CallbackCategories>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<CallbackCategories> call, Response<CallbackCategories> response) {
                CallbackCategories resp = response.body();
                if (resp != null && resp.status.equals("ok")) {
                    displayApiResult(resp.categories);

                } else {
                    onFailRequest();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<CallbackCategories> call, Throwable t) {
                if (!call.isCanceled()) onFailRequest();
            }

        });
    }

    private void onFailRequest() {
        swipeProgress(false);
        if (NetworkCheck.isConnect(getActivity())) {
            showFailedView(true, getString(R.string.failed_text));
        } else {
            showFailedView(true, getString(R.string.no_internet_text));
        }
    }

    private void requestAction() {
        showFailedView(false, "");
        swipeProgress(true);
        showNoItemView(false);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                requestCategoriesApi();

            }
        }, Constant.DELAY_TIME);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        swipeProgress(false);
        if(callbackCall != null && callbackCall.isExecuted()){
            callbackCall.cancel();
        }
    }

    private void showFailedView(boolean flag, String message) {
        View lyt_failed = (View) root_view.findViewById(R.id.lyt_failed_category);
        ((TextView) root_view.findViewById(R.id.failed_message)).setText(message);
        if (flag) {
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            lyt_failed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            lyt_failed.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        ((Button) root_view.findViewById(R.id.failed_retry)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                requestAction();
            }
        });
    }

    private void showNoItemView(boolean show) {
        View lyt_no_item = (View) root_view.findViewById(R.id.lyt_no_item_category);
        ((TextView) root_view.findViewById(R.id.no_item_message)).setText(R.string.no_category);
        if (show) {
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            lyt_no_item.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            lyt_no_item.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    private void swipeProgress(final boolean show) {
        if (!show) {
            swipe_refresh.setRefreshing(show);
            return;
        }
        swipe_refresh.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                swipe_refresh.setRefreshing(show);
            }
        });
    }
}


`
```

Update : AdapterCategory Codes

```
public class AdapterCategory extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterCategory.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Category> items = new ArrayList<>();

    private Context ctx;
    private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, Category obj, int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mOnItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public AdapterCategory(Context context, List<Category> items) {
        this.items = items;
        ctx = context;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView name;
        public TextView post_count;
        public LinearLayout lyt_parent;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            post_count = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.post_count);
            lyt_parent = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.lyt_parent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_category, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Category c = items.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(Html.fromHtml(c.title));
        holder.post_count.setText(c.post_count+"");

        holder.lyt_parent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                    mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(view, c, position);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void setListData(List<Category> items){
        this.items = items;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void resetListData() {
        this.items = new ArrayList<>();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

}
```

Comment: share your AdapterCategory code

Comment: Do you want to add recycler view item click event?

Comment: @VinayakB already shared . help me please